# Disply Images Side by Side on Mobile

Tags: html, css

On my home page under Quick Links, I have some images. On the desktop, they display PERFECTLY. On mobile, however, they don't. I want to have them display 3 side by side in a row (so row 1 has 3, row 2 has 3, and row 3 has 3). But I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried adding CSS and div styling, nothing does it. I need help. Please speak to me at the kindergarten level as I'm still learning this.

Website: tjstaste.com

Here is what I have in the HTML widget (the class was an attempt to get it to work with CSS but it didn't):

```html
<div id="content-mobile" class="side-by-side"><!-- wp:columns -->
<div class="wp-block-columns"><!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:group -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container"><!-- wp:image {"id":9820,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/recipe-index/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Recipe-Index-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9820"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9810,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/smoothies-shakes/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Smoothies-Shakes-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9810"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9812,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/creamers/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Coffee-Creamers-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9812"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:group -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container"><!-- wp:image {"id":9816,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/courses/main-dishes/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Main-Dishes-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9816"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9824,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/courses/soups-salads/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Soups-Salads-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9824"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9814,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/creme-brulee/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Creme-Brulees-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9814"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:image {"id":9818,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/reader-favorites/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Reader-Faves-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9818"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9826,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/menu-plans/weekly-menu-plans/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Weekly-Menus-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9826"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9822,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/menu-plans/seasonal-menu-plans/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Seasonal-Menus-A-1.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9822"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns --></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add media queries to your css style-sheet.
Try This:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:740px){
.wp-block-group__inner-container, .wp-block-column{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="content-mobile" class="side-by-side"><!-- wp:columns -->
<div class="wp-block-columns"><!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:group -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container"><!-- wp:image {"id":9820,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/recipe-index/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Recipe-Index-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9820"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9810,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/smoothies-shakes/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Smoothies-Shakes-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9810"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9812,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/creamers/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Coffee-Creamers-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9812"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:group -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container"><!-- wp:image {"id":9816,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/courses/main-dishes/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Main-Dishes-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9816"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9824,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/courses/soups-salads/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Soups-Salads-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9824"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9814,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/creme-brulee/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Creme-Brulees-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9814"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:image {"id":9818,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/reader-favorites/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Reader-Faves-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9818"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9826,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/menu-plans/weekly-menu-plans/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Weekly-Menus-A.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9826"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9822,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://tjstaste.com/category/menu-plans/seasonal-menu-plans/"><img src="https://tjstaste.com/tjstaste-uploads/2020/02/Seasonal-Menus-A-1.png" alt="" class="wp-image-9822"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns --></div>
```

Comment: You are the best, Hamid! That worked, but is there also a way to horizontally center the rows on mobile? On my phone they're all to the left.

Comment: Never mind...I added     justify-content: center; and that did it. Thank you SO much!